# Programmatically create View with multiple content types

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom list that has 1 content type. That content type has a parent content type that it inheieritits from.

Type 1 has 3 fields:

Field A,
Field B,
Field C

Type 2 has 2 fields and inherits Type 1:

Field D,
Field E

I am Programmatically creating a few views. When I do this through the SP UI it works great, not complaints, but when I do it in a PowerShell script, like so:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb [Site URL]
$list = $web.Lists[ListName]

$list.Views.Add($viewName, $includeFieldsCollection, $query, 100, $true, $false)
$web.Dispose()
```

Where $includeFieldsCollection is all fields A-E.

I get the error:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "6" argument(s): "Column 'Field A' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."
```

How can I do this in PowerShell? It does not want to see the columns that its getting from the higher scope. If I look at the SP UI they show up just fine.

Thank you.

Edit: I have to correct the issue.

Comment: What `ListName` stands for? Shoudn't be a string there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the column names you are passing to the powershell function are the **internal** names?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms480493.aspx

Normally spaces are replaced with `_x0200_`

```
Field A would be Field_x0200_A
```

Comment: I realized the issue was something else entirely, but this answer was something I did encounter. So I am marking it as the answer. The actual issue ended up being the way the scripts were laid out. I got it working though! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the list I'm working with is actually using the correct content type and fields. You can check them using:

`$list.fields | format-table`

and

`$list.contenttypes | format-table`